# Is The "order" Property in CDbCriteria Secure?

Tags: yii

Is the following code secure against the SQL injection?

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$arySort= json_decode($_GET['sort']);
$criteria->order= $arySort[0]->property . ' ' .  $arySort[0]->direction;

Person::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

If not, what should I do to make sure there is no danger in the "order" property of the `CDbCriteria` object?

Should I use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)?

Comment: Do you use CGridView to render data?

Comment: No. I am using ExtJs. However I don't think CGridView can make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not enogh think only about sql injection. You have to check data from json array, couse wrong field name or wrong direction could be sent.

So

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $arySort= json_decode($_GET['sort']);
    $criteria->order=$this->prepareSort($_GET['sort']);
    Person::model()->findAll($criteria);

    public function prepareSort($arySort)
    {
        $property='t.id';
        $direction='ASC'
        if(is_seet($arySort[0])
        {
            if(in_array($arySort[0]->property, array_keys($this->attributes))
                $property=$arySort[0]->property;
            if(in_array($arySort[0]->direction, array('ASC', 'DESC')))
                $direction=$arySort[0]->direction;
        }
        return $property.' '.$direction;
    }
```

PS

In the case of using CGridView something like this

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('t.id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('t.title',$this->title,true);
    $criteria->compare('content',$this->content,true);
    $criteria->compare('url',$this->url,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider(
        $this,
        array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'title ASC',
                'attributes'=>array(
                    '*'
                )
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>20,
            ),
        )
    );
}
```